# Switching between two dropdownlist by clicking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a page that displays 2 dropdowns and a checkbox. 
I want a situation where when you click on the checkbox it will determine which dropdownlist to use

Default dropdown displays the dropdownlist below

```
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlprojects", Model.GetProjectInformationActive.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.GetProjectInformationActive.SelectedProject, new { @class = "selactive", @name="ddlprojects", @onchange="javascript:GetStatusDate(this.value);"})
```

when you check the displayallproj checkbox display the dropdownlist below. This should be vice versa

```
       @Html.DropDownList("ddlprojects", Model.GetProjectInformationInActive.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.GetProjectInformationInActive.SelectedProject, new { @class = "selinactive", @name = "ddlprojects", @onchange = "javascript:GetStatusDate(this.value);" })
```

Here is the html section

```
        <div id="ProjID">
            <label for="SelectProjID">Project:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlprojects", Model.GetProjectInformationActive.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.GetProjectInformationActive.SelectedProject, new { @class = "selactive", @name="ddlprojects", @onchange="javascript:GetStatusDate(this.value);"}) 
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlprojects", Model.GetProjectInformationInActive.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.GetProjectInformationInActive.SelectedProject, new { @class = "selinactive", @name = "ddlprojects", @onchange = "javascript:GetStatusDate(this.value);" })         

            <div id="DisplayAllProjects">
                <input type="checkbox" value="DisplayAllProj" name="AllProj" id="AllProj">
                <label for="SelectAll">Display ALL projects, active and inactive. (Active projects shown by default.)</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="StatDate">               
            <label for="SelectStatDate">Status Date:</label>
            <select id="ddlstatusdate" name="ddlstatusdate" >Select status date</select>
        </div>
```

Here is the jquery that should control this behaviour

```
         //To do
        $('#AllProj').click(function () {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){

            }
            else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){

            }
        });
```

Please note that for any active dropdownlist, I am using the ID and using it to pull some other information

```
         $('#ddlstatusdate').on('change', function () {

         var selectedPrjId = $('#ddlprojects').val();
         var things = $('#ddlstatusdate').val();

         $.get('@Url.Action("GetNoteResult", "Home")', { 'selectedData': things, 'selectedProjectId': selectedPrjId }, function (result) {
             $('#ProgressHealth').html(result);
         });

    });
```

Problem: The two dropdown list renders data at any point in time when you look at the html so my on change event for the ddlstatusdate is
        getting confused and returning selectedPrjId = "" since data for the first and second dropdownlist is loaded on the page.

How can I solve this problem such that the data for the active dropdownlist is the only one rendered in the html at any point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your code

remove `@name="ddlprojects"` - (the method already generates `name="ddlprojects"` anyway but if you changed it to say `@name="xyz"` your will see that it does nothing at all).

Your generating invalid html because both dropdownlists have `id="ddlprojects"` (its invalid html and you jquery selectors wont work), so use `new { id = "", @class = "ddlprojects" }` to remove the `id` attribute and use a class name

Then your script can be (not sure which one should be hidden if checked)

```
$('#AllProj').click(function () {
    $('.ddlprojects').show();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.ddlprojects').first().hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.ddlprojects').last().hide();
    }
});
```

You will also need to change your `$('#ddlstatusdate').on('change', function () {` to select only the visible dropdownlist assuming that's the one you want to get the selected value from, for example `$('.ddlprojects').not(':hidden');`

And finally you will need a script to hide one or other of the dropdownlists based on the initial value of checkbox that runs when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is coming around now. I don't really understand this statement  $('.ddlprojects').not(':hidden');  where will I add this?

Comment: Thanks again. Here is what I did and it works. I added this line.   var obj = $('.ddlprojects').not(':hidden');
 var selectedPrjId = obj.val();

Comment: I guess it was the same Id that messed me up and the .not('hidden') syntax is very powerful.